# How to use control state in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net

Below is my simple code to use control state in a custom control,

```
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:WebCustomControl1 runat=server></{0}:WebCustomControl1>")]
public class WebCustomControl1 : WebControl
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }
    private string text;

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write(Text);
    }

    protected override void OnInit(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Page.RequiresControlState(this);
    }

    protected override object SaveControlState()
    {
        object baseSate = base.SaveControlState();
        return new Pair(baseSate, Text);
    }

    protected override void LoadControlState(object savedState)
    {
        Pair value = savedState as Pair;
        text = value.Second;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.. The SaveControlState and LoadControlState are not firing. can someone help me..?

Below is the aspx Code. Here is where i use the custom control.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="WebApplication1" Namespace="WebApplication1" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>`enter code here`
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <cc1:WebCustomControl1 ID="WebCustomControl1_1"  runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show the markup code for the control on .aspx page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've called `RequiresControlState`

> Determines whether the specified Control object is registered to participate in control state management.`

But you should call `RegisterRequiresControlState`

> Registers a control as one whose control state must be persisted.